# Conditional import: import if exists

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Is there a way to check for the file existence before importing it?

```
(async () => {
    let module;
    try {
        module = await import("./mymodule.js");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("not found")
    }

})()
```

Comment: There isn't any in the JavaScript spec, but if you need to do this in a specific environment, there may be an environment-specific answer. But what you're doing above is reasonable.

Comment: no specific environment, the browser is the environment

Comment: That *is* a specific environment. :-)

Answer (score 3):

None defined in the JavaScript specification, no. Your approach of falling back if you get a rejection from `import()` seems reasonable. If that's at the module level, soon you won't even need the function wrapper on the `try`/`catch` thanks to [top level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await).

Comment: the problem with that approach is I'm flooding the console with `404` errors, I'm supposed to import a lot of file (IF they exist)

Comment: @alfredopacino - Sadly I don't think there's a way around that unless you can get server support (e.g., something you can query to ask if the file exists), since even ajax will give a 404.